# How to mock Rethinkdb for unit test my DAO's in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sinon, rethinkdb

What is the best approach to mock / stub Rethinkdb in order to unit test my DAO's with NodeJS? I have tried some approaches with Sinon and Proxyquire but I got stuck on the connection object.

Examples are welcome.

Cheers,

Gyo

Comment: [reqlite](https://github.com/neumino/reqlite) is an old project that might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [rethinkdbdash](https://npmjs.org/package/rethinkdbdash), you can use [mock-require](https://npmjs.org/package/mock-require) with [rethinkdb-mock](https://npmjs.org/package/rethinkdb-mock) to avoid connections altogether. Plus, you can initialize the dataset with JSON or a plain object.

```
require('mock-require')('rethinkdbdash', require('rethinkdb-mock'));

const rethinkdb = require('rethinkdbdash');
const r = rethinkdb();

// Load data from a JSON file.
r.load(__dirname, 'test_data.json');

// Set table data, erasing previous data in those tables.
r.init({
  users: [
    {id: 1, name: 'John'}
  ]
});
```